# Code failing validation - pre and p tags inside li

Tags: html, tags

I've got some code where I'm using ordered and unordered lists.   Within the list items I have used `<p>` and `<pre>` tags to make certain text stand out.   When I run the code through the W3C validator, I get the following error messages:

```
Element p not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing errors from this subtree.)

Element pre not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing errors from this subtree.)
```

Here's a snippet of the code (with "dummy text" for the most part, just to give you an idea of what I'm doing):

```
<ul>
    <li>e complectitur sit ut, ex his tale assueverit, euismod nostrum delicatissimi usu in.</li>

    <pre>sometext></pre>

    <li>Nec ex habeo lobortis. Ex has suscipit adversarium, mentitum dissentiet</li>

    <pre>some more text</pre>
</ul>
```

So, two questions:

1. If this renders correctly on a web page, why is the validator reporting it as a problem?
2. Is there some alternative I can use to make text stand out within an ordered/unordered list that will pass validation?

Comment: try to use inline element such as 'span'

Answer (score 0):

1. The validator looks at all the rules defined by the W3C. It doesn't mean it's not gonna work. But it might not work in all browser or in the future.
2. It really depends what outpud you need. You might be ok using `<br />` and `<span>`. You might have to change your `<ul>` and `<li>` with divs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HTML` code is not valid. Period.

The browsers try to render your code even if it is invalid. The result depends highly on the browser and the version.

According to `HTML` in the tag `<ul>` only `<li>` may be nested. You may nest your `<p>` or `<pre>` inside the tag `<li>`, e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li>e complectitur sit ut, ex his tale assueverit, euismod nostrum delicatissimi usu in.</li>
    <li><pre>sometext></pre></li>
    <li>Nec ex habeo lobortis. Ex has suscipit adversarium, mentitum dissentiet</li>
    <li><pre>some more text</pre></li>
</ul>
```